# If an infinite set $S$ of positive integers is equidistributed, is $S+S$ also equidistributed?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, additive-combinatorics, sumset

By $S+S$, I mean $\{x+y,$ with $x,y \in S\}$. By equidistributed, I mean equidistributed in residue classes, as defined [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365326/congruential-equidistribution-prime-numbers-and-goldbach-conjecture) (the definition is very intuitive, and examples of such equidistributed sets are provided on that page).

My goal here is to prove that if $S$ is equidistributed and contains enough elements (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365626/prime-gap-distribution-in-residue-classes-and-goldbach-type-conjectures)), then $S+S$ covers all the positive integers except a finite number of them. The first step, I think, would be to prove that $S+S$ is equidistributed. I d guess the proof is not difficult and this fact has probably been established, but I could not find a reference.

The result seems obvious if you consider "equidistribution modulo 1" instead, so I suppose it can also be derived (probably in a similar way) for "equidistribution in residue classes", as the two concepts are closely related and based on a similar Weyl criterion (a continuous version for modulo 1, a discrete version for residue classes.)

**Special case**

If the infinite set $S$ of positive integers is such that if $x,y\in S$ then $x+y\notin S$, it is easy to prove that $S$ equidistributed implies $S+S$ is also equidistributed. Note that $S$ is called a [Sidon set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence) or  [sum-free set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-free_set).
Let $N_S(z)$ be the number of elements of $S$ less or equal to $z$, and let's assume that

$$N_S(z)\sim \frac{a z^b}{(\log z)^c} \mbox{ as } z\rightarrow\infty$$

where $a,b,c$ are non-negative real numbers with $b\leq 1$. The sets that I am interested in all have $b>\frac{1}{2}$, for instance, pseudo-primes ($a=b=c=1$) or [pseudo-superprimes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364772/paradox-in-additive-combinatorics) ($a=b=1, c=2$). Such sets satisfy this conjecture A (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365626/prime-gap-distribution-in-residue-classes-and-goldbach-type-conjectures)) : all but a finite number of positive integers can be written as $z=x+y$ with $x, y \in S$. That conjecture would imply that $S+S$ is de facto equidistributed, since essentially, in this case $S+S$ it is the set of all positive integers minus a finite number of them. However, that conjecture A is precisely what I would want to prove, so I can not use it as a justification to establish the much weaker result that $S+S$ is supposedly equidistributed if $b>\frac{1}{2}$ and $S$ is equidistributed. If $b\leq \frac{1}{2}$, conjecture A is not true.

**Hints to prove the result and win the bounty**

In case it is not true, a counter-example will do. Assuming it is correct, a sketch of a proof for a simple case is enough. Here is how it could start.

Let $T = S+S$ and

$$S(n,q) = \{x\in S, x=q \bmod{n}\}.$$

We have

$$T(n,q) = \bigcup_{p=0}^{n-1}\Big[S(n,p) + S(n,(q-p) \bmod{n} )\Big]$$
$$T=\bigcup_{q=0}^{n-1}T(n,q)$$

$T(n,q)$ is the subset of elements of $T$ that are equal to $q$ modulo $n$. The subsets $T(n,q)$ for any given $n>1$ form a partition of $T$. However the first union for $T(n,q)$ consists of potentially overlapping sets, making the problem non-trivial. Proving the result consists in proving that for any integer $n>1$ and $0\leq q,q'<n$ we have

$$\frac{N_{T(n,q)}(z)} {N_{T(n,q')}(z)}\rightarrow 1 \mbox{ as } z\rightarrow \infty.$$

Again $N_T(z)$ counts the number of elements of $T$ less than or equal to $z$. We can focus on sets $S$ such that

$$N_S(z) \sim \frac{a z^b}{(\log z)^c} $$

with $0\leq b \leq \frac{1}{2}$. I will offer the bounty even if the proof is only for the special case $b=\frac{1}{2}, c=0$ and $n=2$. For computer experiments (generating such a set $S$ that is supposed to be equidistributed), proceed as follows: the positive integer $k$ belongs to $S$ if and only if $U_k < a/(2\sqrt{z})$ where the $U_k$'s are independent uniform deviates on $[0, 1]$.

I did some experiments and here are the results, using $n=12, b=\frac{1}{2}$ and looking at all elements of $S$ and $T=S+S$ up to $10^6$:

[image]

Equidistribution in $S$ (modulo $n=12$ in this case) means that the "Ratio_1" tend to be identical and equal to $\frac{1}{n}$as you look at more and more elements of $S$, while equidistribution in $T$ means that the "Ratio_2" tend to be identical also converging to $\frac{1}{n}$.

I also did the same test on the set $S$ of perfect squares, which is notoriously not equidistributed. The results are below.

[image]

Final notes:

- For perfect squares, $a=1, b=\frac{1}{2}, c=0$. Even though $T$, the set of sums of two perfect squares is not equidistributed, the set $T+T$ is the set of all non-negative integers, and is thus equidistributed (that set of course has $a=0, b=1, c=0$).
- The last table suggests that the equations $x^2 + y^2 = 12z+ 3$, $x^2 + y^2 = 12z+ 7$, $x^2 + y^2 = 12z+ 11$ do not have integer solutions, while $x^2 + y^2 = 12z$, $x^2 + y^2 = 12z+6$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 12z+9$ might have only finitely many solutions.

Comment: This can give the false impression that we are making little progress towards proving Goldbach and other similar conjectures. I believe this is not the case, because the set $S$ of primes is also notoriously non-equidistributed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$S+S$ need not be equidistributed.

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of even positive integers such that $$a_{n+1} > 3+a_n+a_{n-1}+\dots+a_2+a_1$$ for each $n \ge 1$ and such that $\{\frac{a_n}{2} : n \ge 1\}$ is equidistributed. It should be clear that such a sequence exists; let me know if you want details. Let $$S = \cup_{n=1}^\infty \{a_n,a_n+1\}.$$ Then $S$ is equidistributed: it is clearly equidistributed mod $2$, and that $\{\frac{a_n}{2} : n \ge 1\}$ is equidistributed implies $S$ is equidistributed mod $n$, for any $n \ge 3$.

Now, $S+S = \cup_{1 \le n \le m < \infty} \{a_n+a_m,a_n+a_m+1,a_n+a_m+2\}$. Note the union is a disjoint one, since $a_{n+1} > 3+a_n+\dots+a_1$ for each $n \ge 1$. Therefore, $S+S$ is not equidistributed mod $2$, since $2$ out of $3$ of $a_n+a_m, a_n+a_m+1,a_n+a_m+2$ (namely, the first and the third) are even.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't yet looked in detail at your counter-example. Wondering what extra conditions on $S$ might be needed to warrant that $S+S$ is equidistributed. Also wondering if your set $S$ satisfies the same asymptotic class of distributions as discussed in my question. I will look into this.

Comment: @VincentGranville I'm not sure what extra conditions would help. My example stems from the fact (and basically is just the fact) that $\{1,2\}+\{1,2\} = \{2,3,4\}$ is not even equidistributed mod $2$.

Comment: @ mathworker21: yes, I am aware that this does not work at all with finite sets. Sets need to be infinite, and your counter-example is.

Comment: @VincentGranville what?? the whole point of my answer was showing that this finite example transfers to an infinite example.

Comment: @ mathworker21: yes, and I totally agree with you. What I meant is "your example is infinite and thus qualifies". Not sure why you understood it differently.

Comment: @VincentGranville I understood exactly what you were saying. My point was that your comment was completely irrelevant. My answer essentially draws an equivalence between finite and infinite sets. So when I said that I'm not sure what extra conditions would help, you responding by bringing up the distinction between finite and infinite sets is irrelevant.